# CONVERT to XT format from matrix format

Tags: matrix, time-series

I have a matrix X: 131*29 format, I want to convert it to "xts object" in year pattern. I have limited R language knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(xts)
data <- matrix(rnorm(n = 131 * 29), ncol = 29)
timeindex <-
  seq.Date(from = as.Date("1900-01-01"),
           by = "years",
           length.out = 131)

myxts <- xts(x = data, order.by = timeindex)

> head(myxts[, c(1:3)])
                  [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
1900-01-01 -0.05270081  0.2177585 -0.01717907
1901-01-01 -0.50514942 -0.7325821  0.90430048
1902-01-01 -0.04710051 -0.9079267  0.53016427
1903-01-01  0.23658303 -1.2000134  0.99272586
1904-01-01  0.67484632 -2.3547689  1.44805954
1905-01-01  1.22531681  1.2777569  0.43727875
```